# How to read data from file geodatabase tables dynamically?

Tags: c#, database, gis, arcgis, shapefile

```
foreach(Row in table.Search("*","",rowinstance.recycle()))
{
  City current_city = new City();
  current_city.cityname = row.GetString("cityname");

  PointShapeBuffer geometry = row.GetGeometry();
  psri.FileGdb.point point = geometry.point;
  current_city.xcord = point.x;
  current_city.ycord = point.y;
  current_city.popCateogry = row.getInteger("pop");

}
```

In above code i am retrieving different values from one row like row.GetString(), row.GetInteger() etc, How about if I don't know the data type of that row, how can I retrieve values from row generically?
I have tried `var type = row.GetType()` but its not working, its giving some other sort of information, not about the datatype.

Comment: Is this ArcObjects-code? Or ArcGIS Runtime? Or ...?

Answer (score 2):

A *row* in a geodatabase feature class or table will have multiple associated data types. Using your example code, each row will have a geometry attribute, a population attribute (integer), a city name attribute (string), and so on.

You should instead by finding the data type of each attribute (field) before you try to access data from it, and then have appropriate conditionals to handle that.

[IField.Type Property (Esri reference page)](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IField_Type.htm) may get you started.